# Прерывается ли соединение по протоколу WebSocket, если клиент отправляет http запрос, или эти 2 протокола могут работать параллельно?

Tags: javascript, http, websocket

Прерывается ли соединение по протоколу WebSocket, если клиент отправляет http запрос, или эти 2 протокола могут работать параллельно? Хочу понять, могу ли я транслировать видеопток по протоколу вебсоккет и что то делать с ним в браузере, или при первом http запросе сервер прервет соединение.

Comment: Короткий ответ: не прерывается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изначальный HTTP - это **синхронный** протокол обмена данными.

WebSocket, если говорить грубо, то - надстройка над HTTP, которая делает его **асинхронным**.

То есть, тут уже будет все работать так же, как с простыми TCP-пакетами в плане соединения.

Поскольку я мог передать информацию достаточно искаженно, и в парадигме именно моего, скажем так, "внутреннего я", то приложу Вам ссылку на хабр, где все разложено по полочкам: [WebSocket - полноценный асинхронный веб](https://habr.com/ru/post/79038/)

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что я хотел узнать